# Problem while doing vector manipulation in Python.(vector component perpendicular to reference vector)

Tags: python, astropy

I have a set of coordinates which I would like to manipulate and get desired results. I need to find the horizontal projection of some vector with respect to a reference vector ie, if v1(x1,y1,z1) represent the reference unit vector and v2(x2,y2,z2) be some random vector, I want to find the projection of v2 perpendicular to the direction of v1.

The figurative representation of the required is given as,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i3RQm--nLc1dIdZGMpt7oc5KLahOJySk/view?usp=sharing

The vectorial representation is required as

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12QLIoIJ0wckLa8sIgJ8ynMaD33PWrgxQ/view?usp=sharing

The code that I have written is as follows,

```
catalog=ascii.read("catalog.txt",'r',format='fixed_width_no_header', fast_reader=False, delimiter="\s",names=x,col_starts=y,col_ends=z)
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
for i in range(0,len(catalog['PSRJ'])):
    catalog['DECJD'][i] = catalog['DECJD'][i]+90
    x.append(sin(catalog['DECJD'][i])*cos(catalog['RAJD'][i]))
    y.append(sin(catalog['DECJD'][i])*sin(catalog['RAJD'][i]))
    z.append(cos(catalog['DECJD'][i]))

coord=[]    
for i in range(0,len(catalog['PSRJ'])):
    coord.append([x[i],y[i],z[i]])

def norm(k):
    p=[0.0,0.0,0.0]
    p[0]=k[0]/(k[0]**2+k[1]**2+k[2]**2)**0.5
    p[1]=k[1]/(k[0]**2+k[1]**2+k[2]**2)**0.5
    p[2]=k[2]/(k[0]**2+k[1]**2+k[2]**2)**0.5
    return([p[0],p[1],p[2]])

direc = norm(coord[]) #insert key for required coordinate

pix=[]

print(direc)

for i in range(0,len(catalog['PSRJ'])):
    if a-5<=catalog['RAJD'][i]<=a+5 and b-5<=catalog['DECJD'][i]<=b+5:
        pix.append(coord[i])
        if pix[-1]==f:
            p=len(pix)
            print('p',pix)
        val=pix
        count=count+1
                    
for i in range(0,count):
     for j in range(0,3):
          if not(i==p-1):
               k=np.dot(direc,pix[i])
               val[i][j]=direc[j]*k
               val[i][j]=pix[i][j]-val[i][j]
          else:
               val[i][j]=0.0
print(val)
```

coord is list containing position vectors,
eg:[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]...]

f is the reference coordinate,
eg:[a,b,c]

OUTPUTS:

```
[0.049780917594520344, 0.9791671435583665, -0.19685925230782697]
p= 1 
 [[0.049780917594520344, 0.9791671435583665, -0.19685925230782697]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

```
[-0.813400538291293, 0.4058994949023155, 0.41668353020665466]
p= 2 
 [[0.683288067396023, -0.16836586544306054, -0.7104719222515533], [-0.813400538291293, 0.4058994949023155, 0.41668353020665466]]
[[-0.0, -0.0, -0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

```
[0.15331177729205145, -0.40555298841701465, 0.9011227843804535]
p= 2 
 [[0.08556174481590322, 0.8925106169941267, -0.4428362974924498], [0.15331177729205145, -0.40555298841701465, 0.9011227843804535]]
[[-0.0, -0.0, -0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

```
[0.4561283699625753, 0.08868628538946206, 0.8854838524214335]
p= 3 
 [[0.016015167632180395, 0.07982154161648915, -0.9966805084377242], [-0.39320614327231507, 0.918593873485819, -0.03967649792044076], [0.4561283699625753, 0.08868628538946206, 0.8854838524214335]]
[[-0.0, -0.0, -0.0], [-0.0, 0.0, -0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

The end result I am getting is null vectors, I don't know if it is my calculation causing the issue, Any insight into the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Your "norm" function is not correct.  The computation for k[1] is using the NEW value for k[0], and the computation for k[2] is using the NEW values for k[0] and k[1].  You should precompute the denominator to avoid that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your question.  What are the google drive links you included in your question?  They are not accessible, and in any case external links are generally discouraged.  You can use the question editing tools to post images by uploading them directly to imgur.

Comment: Also, since you mentioned Astropy, can you give more details (e.g. as code) of what `catalog` is and what `coord` is and how you obtained them?  In other words, please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It seems you are likely using inefficient index/loop based operations, whereas if you are using Astropy you are most likely doing something with with numpy arrays.  Eg if you have a reference vector `v0 = np.array([1, 2, 3])` and an array of vectors `v = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])` their dot product is `np.dot(v0, v.T)`

Comment: @TimRoberts - oh yeah, that's my mistake. I have no previous programing experience, I am building on an idea that I have, may be that's where I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Iguananaut - fixed link issue and the code has been edited.

Comment: I am still getting zeros.

Comment: This cannot be your code, because `norm(coord[])` is a syntax error in Python.  Give us some REAL DATA and we can help you explore this.  I do want to point out that  you are adding 90 to catalog['DECJD"] as if it were degrees, but the Python math.sin and math.cos expect radians.

Comment: And what are "a" and "b" here?  And remember that range(0,x) is the same as range(x).